# I get a error 80070057 by filling a ListBox

Tags: vba, ms-word, listbox

I do not understand the world anymore.
Hope for help.

I'm filling an ListBox:

```
    lstHst.Clear
    lstHst.AddItem
    Debug.Print lstHst.ListCount; Tab; lstHst.ColumnCount
    For i = 0 To lstHst.ColumnCount - 1
        Debug.Print lstHst.Column(i, 0)
    Next
```

Debug.Print shows 15 Columns.
But after 9 Columns i get an error 80070057

```
 1             15 
Null
Null
```

Comment: Even though your column count is set to 15, you're limited to 10 columns when using the AddItem method.

Comment: Fill a two dimensional array with the desired data, and then assign the array to the List property of the ListBox object.

Comment: ok thanks, so this is a VBA limitation ....